# Beta integral transformation

Tags: special-functions, transformation

It's a homework task and I can't get past the last step.

Task is to prove that
$$
B(x,y)=\int\limits_0^1 \frac{\tau^{x-1}+\tau^{y-1}}{(1+\tau)^{x+y}} \mathrm{d}\tau
$$

By substituting $t=\frac{1}{\tau+1}$ into beta integral
$$
B(x,y)=\int\limits_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\mathrm{d}t
$$

and repeating it with substition $t=\frac{\tau}{\tau+1}$ and counting both results together it can be shown that
$$
2B(x,y)=\int\limits_0^{+\infty} \frac{\tau^{x-1}+\tau^{y-1}}{(1+\tau)^{x+y}} \mathrm{d}\tau
$$

Can this result be transformed into the needed one? Or should the initial steps be different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\tau^{x-1}}{(1+\tau)^{x+y}}\mathrm d\tau\ \stackrel{\sigma=1/\tau}{=}\ \int_0^1\frac{\sigma^{y-1}}{(1+\sigma)^{x+y}}\mathrm d\sigma$$
Thus the initial steps you show are all right.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that :)