# How to evaluate the integral $\int_1^{\infty}[u^\alpha-(u-1)^{\alpha}]^2du$?

Tags: definite-integrals

The integral
\begin{equation}
I=\int_1^{\infty}[u^\alpha-(u-1)^{\alpha}]^2du,\quad -1/2<\alpha<1/2
\end{equation}
comes from the stochastic process fractional Brownian motion.

Can someone show how to evaluate it?

Thank you!

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Reply to Lucian:

Do you mean the following derivation?

By letting $t=1/u$, the integral becomes

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I&=\int_0^1\left[t^{-2\alpha-2}-2t^{-2\alpha-2}(1-t)^\alpha + t^{-2\alpha-2}(1-t)^{2\alpha}  \right]dt\\
&=\int_0^1t^{-2\alpha-2}dt+\int_0^1-2t^{-2\alpha-2}(1-t)^\alpha dt + \int_0^1t^{-2\alpha-2}(1-t)^{2\alpha}dt \\
&=I_1+I_2+I_3
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I_1&=\left.\frac{t^{-2\alpha-1}}{-2\alpha-1}\right|_0^1=\infty\\
I_2&=-2B(-2\alpha-1,\alpha+1)=-2\frac{\Gamma(-2\alpha-1)\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}\\
I_3&=B(-2\alpha-1,2\alpha+1)=\frac{\Gamma(-2\alpha-1)\Gamma(2\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(0)}=0\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The above derivations are not correct since beta function $B(w,v)$ requires $w,v>0$ and $I_1$ is divergent. What may be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Actually, your third term is undefined, since it is of the form $\infty-\infty$. The first and last term of the integrand cannot be separated like this, due to issues of convergence. They'll have both to remain inside the same integral sign. You will have to compute a limit, whose value is $-\dfrac1{2a+1}$. This, together with $I_2$, will yield the final result.

Comment: Actually, all those three integrals diverge simultaneously. So the cancellation effect occurs to yield a finite value only when we consider all those terms inside the integral.

Comment: @Lucian Could you detail the derivation since I can't figure out myself

Comment: @sos440: No. $I_2$ definitely converges.

Comment: @Lucian, $-2\alpha-2 < -1$ shows that $t^{-2\alpha-2}(1-t)^{\alpha} \sim t^{-2\alpha-2}$ near $t = 0$, which makes $I_{2}$ diverge.

Comment: @ecook: Use the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844216) as inspiration.

Comment: @sos440: What you wrote is $-\dfrac{I_2}2-I_1$, which indeed diverges.

Comment: @Lucian, Why is the integral $\int_{0}^{1} t^{-2a-2}(1-t)^{a} \, dt$ equal to $-\frac{1}{2}I_{2} - I_{1}$, instead of just $-\frac{1}{2}I_{2}$?

Comment: @sos440: Never mind. I thought you wrote a minus in place of a tilde.

Answer (score 6):

**EDITED.** The major obstacle when calculating the integral

$$ I
= \int_{1}^{\infty} (u^{\alpha} - (u-1)^{\alpha})^{2} \, du
= \int_{0}^{1} x^{-2\alpha-2}(1 - (1-x)^{\alpha})^{2} \, dx $$

is that, within the range $|\alpha| < \frac{1}{2}$, the term $x^{-2\alpha-2}$ has singularity at $x = 0$ which gives rise to infinity when it is not cancelled out appropriately. In order words, splitting the integral into three parts gives

\begin{align*}
I_{1} &= \int_{0}^{1} x^{-2\alpha-2} \, dx = \infty, \\
I_{2} &= -2 \int_{0}^{1} x^{-2\alpha-2}(1 - x)^{\alpha} \, dx = -\infty, \\
I_{2} &= \int_{0}^{1} x^{-2\alpha-2}(1 - x)^{2\alpha} \, dx = \infty.
\end{align*}

One way of avoiding this catastrophe is to use the principle of analytic continuation. To utilize this technique, let us introduce auxiliary integral

$$ I(s)
= \int_{1}^{\infty} u^{-s}(u^{\alpha} - (u-1)^{\alpha})^{2} \, du
= \int_{0}^{1} x^{s-2\alpha-2}(1 - (1-x)^{\alpha})^{2} \, dx. $$

For any given $|\alpha| < \frac{1}{2}$, it is not hard to check that $I(s)$ converges and defines an analytic function for $\Re(s) > -2\alpha-1$. Indeed, from the mean value theorem we find that $u^{\alpha} - (u-1)^{\alpha} = \Theta(u^{\alpha-1})$ as $u \to \infty$. Consequently, the integrand is asymptotically
$$ u^{-s}(u^{\alpha} - (u-1)^{\alpha})^{2} = \Theta(u^{-\Re(s)+2\alpha-2}) $$
and hence it becomes integrable.

Moreover, for $\Re(s) > 1+2\alpha$, we have $\Re(s-2\alpha-2) > -1$ and hence we become able to evaluate $I(s)$ by expanding the square and integrating each resulting term as follows:

\begin{align*}
I(s)
&= \int_{0}^{1} x^{s-2\alpha-2} \, dx - 2 \int_{0}^{1} x^{s-2\alpha-2}(1 - x)^{\alpha} \, dx + \int_{0}^{1} x^{s-2\alpha-2}(1 - x)^{2\alpha} \, dx \\
&= \beta(s-2\alpha-1, 1) - 2\beta(s-2\alpha-1, 1+\alpha) + \beta(s-2\alpha-1, 1+2\alpha) \\
&= \Gamma(s-2\alpha-1) \left( \frac{1}{\Gamma(s-2\alpha)} - 2\frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\Gamma(s-\alpha)} + \frac{\Gamma(1+2\alpha)}{\Gamma(s)} \right). \tag{1}
\end{align*}

Now notice that the right-hand side defines a meromorphic function on all of $\Bbb{C}$. So by the principle of analytic continuation, (1) holds for all $\Re(s) > -2\alpha-1$ away from poles of $\Gamma(s-2\alpha-1)$. Now taking limit as as $s \to 0$, we obtain

\begin{align*}
I
&= \Gamma(-2\alpha-1) \left( \frac{1}{\Gamma(-2\alpha)} - 2\frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\Gamma(-\alpha)} \right) \\
&= -\frac{1}{2\alpha+1} - 2\beta(-2\alpha-1, 1+\alpha),
\end{align*}

This coincides with Lucian's answer, and also coincides with numerical tests with *Mathematica*.

---

**OLD ANSWER.** It seems that the exact closed form for the integral seems hard to obtain. Instead, some approximations are possible. For example, I obtained

$$ \frac{2\alpha^{2}}{1-4\alpha^{2}} \leq I \leq \frac{2\alpha^{2}}{(1-4\alpha^{2})(\alpha + \frac{1}{2})}. $$

In particular, we have $I = \Theta(\alpha^{2})$ near $\alpha =0$ and $I ~ \sim (4-8\alpha)^{-1}$ as $\alpha \to \frac{1}{2}^{-}$.

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong. As already stated above, the closed form is $$-\dfrac1{2a+1}-2B\big(a+1,-2a-1\big).$$

Comment: @sos440 Wonderful.Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 3):

**Real Variable Approach**
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_1^\infty(u^\alpha-(u-1)^\alpha)^2\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\int_0^{\lambda-1}((u+1)^\alpha-u^\alpha)^2\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{1a}\\
&=\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\left[\int_0^{\lambda-1}(u+1)^{2\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}u-2\int_0^{\lambda-1}(u+1)^\alpha u^\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u+\int_0^{\lambda-1}u^{2\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}u\right]\tag{1b}\\
&=\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\small\left[\frac{\lambda^{2\alpha+1}-1}{2\alpha+1}+\frac{(\lambda-1)^{2\alpha+1}}{2\alpha+1}-2\int_0^{\lambda-1}(u+1)^\alpha u^\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u\right]\tag{1c}\\
&=\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\small\left[\frac{\lambda^{2\alpha+1}-1}{2\alpha+1}+\frac{(\lambda-1)^{2\alpha+1}}{2\alpha+1}-\frac{2(\lambda-1)^{\alpha+1}\lambda^\alpha}{2\alpha+1}-\frac{2\alpha}{2\alpha+1}\int_0^{\lambda-1}(u+1)^{\alpha-1}u^\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u\right]\tag{1d}\\
&=\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\small\left[\frac{\lambda^{2\alpha+1}-1}{2\alpha+1}+\frac{(\lambda-1)^{2\alpha+1}}{2\alpha+1}-\frac{2(\lambda-1)^{\alpha+1}\lambda^\alpha}{2\alpha+1}-\frac{(\lambda-1)^{\alpha+1}\lambda^{\alpha-1}}{2\alpha+1}\right]\\
&-\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\frac{\alpha-1}{2\alpha+1}\int_0^{\lambda-1}(u+1)^{\alpha-2} u^{\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{1e}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{1-\alpha}{2\alpha+1}\,\mathrm{B}(1+\alpha,1-2\alpha)-\frac1{2\alpha+1}\tag{1f}\\[6pt]
&=-2\,\mathrm{B}(1+\alpha,-1-2\alpha)-\frac1{2\alpha+1}\tag{1g}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: substitute $u\mapsto u+1$ and convert improper integral to a limit
$\text{(1b)}$: expand the square
$\text{(1c)}$: evaluate the left and right integrals of $\text{(1b)}$
$\text{(1d)}$: apply $(2)$ with $\beta=\alpha$
$\text{(1e)}$: apply $(2)$ with $\beta=\alpha-1$
$\text{(1f)}$: evaluate the limits using $(3)$
$\text{(1g)}$: use $\mathrm{B}(1+\alpha,1-2\alpha)=\frac{-2\alpha}{1-\alpha}\frac{-1-2\alpha}{-\alpha}\,\mathrm{B}(1+\alpha,-1-2\alpha)$

---

**Integration by Parts to Reduce the Exponent of $\boldsymbol{(u+1)}$**
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\lambda-1}(u+1)^\beta u^\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac1{a+1}\int_0^{\lambda-1}(u+1)^\beta\,\mathrm{d}u^{\alpha+1}\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac{(\lambda-1)^{\alpha+1}\lambda^\beta}{\alpha+1}-\frac\beta{\alpha+1}\int_0^{\lambda-1}(u+1)^{\beta-1}u^{\alpha+1}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac{(\lambda-1)^{\alpha+1}\lambda^\beta}{\alpha+1}-\frac\beta{\alpha+1}\left[\int_0^{\lambda-1}(u+1)^\beta u^\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u-\int_0^{\lambda-1}(u+1)^{\beta-1}u^\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u\right]\tag{2c}\\
&=\frac{(\lambda-1)^{\alpha+1}\lambda^\beta}{\alpha+\beta+1}+\frac\beta{\alpha+\beta+1}\int_0^{\lambda-1}(u+1)^{\beta-1}u^\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: prepare to integrate by parts
$\text{(2b)}$: integrate by parts
$\text{(2c)}$: $u=(u+1)-1$
$\text{(2d)}$: add $\frac\beta{\alpha+1}\int_0^{\lambda-1}(u+1)^\beta u^\alpha\,\mathrm{d}u$ and multiply by $\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha+\beta+1}$

---

**Evaluation of a Limit From $\bf{(1e)}$**
$$
\begin{align}
&\hphantom{=}\lambda^{2\alpha+1}+(\lambda-1)^{2\alpha+1}-2(\lambda-1)^{\alpha+1}\lambda^\alpha-(\lambda-1)^{\alpha+1}\lambda^{\alpha-1}\\
&=\lambda^{2\alpha}+\color{#C00000}{\lambda^{2\alpha}(\lambda-1)+(\lambda-1)^{2\alpha+1}-2(\lambda-1)^{\alpha+1}\lambda^\alpha}-(\lambda-1)^{\alpha+1}\lambda^{\alpha-1}\tag{3a}\\
&=\color{#00A000}{\lambda^{2\alpha}}+\color{#C00000}{(\lambda-1)\left(\lambda^\alpha-(\lambda-1)^\alpha\right)^2}\color{#00A000}{-(\lambda-1)^{\alpha+1}\lambda^{\alpha-1}}\tag{3b}\\
&=(\lambda-1)\left(\lambda^\alpha-(\lambda-1)^\alpha\right)^2+\color{#00A000}{\left(\lambda^{\alpha+1}-(\lambda-1)^{\alpha+1}\right)\lambda^{\alpha-1}}\tag{3c}\\
&\sim\lambda\left(\alpha\lambda^{\alpha-1}\right)^2+\left((\alpha+1)\lambda^\alpha\right)\lambda^{\alpha-1}\tag{3d}\\
&=(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)\lambda^{2\alpha-1}\tag{3e}\\
&\to0\tag{3f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: $\lambda^{2\alpha+1}=\lambda^{2\alpha}(1+(\lambda-1))=\lambda^{2\alpha}+\lambda^{2\alpha}(\lambda-1)$
$\text{(3b)}$: collect red terms
$\text{(3c)}$: collect green terms
$\text{(3d)}$: mean value theorem
$\text{(3e)}$: collect terms
$\text{(3f)}$: $2\alpha-1\lt0$

Comment: Nicely done (+1)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $u=\dfrac1t$ , and then recognize the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral.

Comment: Do you mean the derivation in the post?